# WPF - Setting ToolTip MaxWidth

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, tooltip

I would like to set ToolTip maxwidth property to show long texts properly. In addition I need text wrapping. I used this style:

```
<Style TargetType="ToolTip">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"  MaxWidth="400" TextWrapping='Wrap' />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
</Style>
```

This tooltip style is OK for my purpose. However, it is not effective for some controls which has own tooltip style. For example, tooltip of following button can not appear.

```
<Button>
    <Button.ToolTip>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource firstText}" Text="aaaaaaaaaaaaa"/>
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource secondText}" Text="bbbbbbbbbbbbb"/>    
            <TextBlock Bacground="Red" Text="ccccccccccccc"/>    
        </StackPanel>
    </Button.ToolTip>
</Button>
```

I want to set maxwidth property with text wrapping for **all tooltips**. What can i do for this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by **for some controls which has own tooltip style.**?

Comment: I mean specific tooltips. For example button in example, consist of three textblock.But if I use like as: <Button ToolTip="Hello world.."/>, my style is successfull. So, different tooltips that have different structure can not use my style..

Comment: I upped it, but I think you should explain your **goal** more. There are always better ways of doing things :-).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Following style of ToolTip is useful for me:

```
<Style TargetType="ToolTip" x:Key="InternalToolTipStyle">
    <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="{Binding Path=(lib:ToolTipProperties.MaxWidth)}" />
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"  >
                    <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                        </Style>
                    </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                </ContentPresenter>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

With this style, tooltip of following button appears properly:

```
<Button>
<Button.ToolTip>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource firstText}" Text="aaaaaaaaaaaaa"/>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource secondText}" Text="bbbbbbbbbbbbb"/>    
        <TextBlock Bacground="Red" Text="ccccccccccccc"/>    
    </StackPanel>
</Button.ToolTip>
```

Answer (score 35):

I avoid using Template because a lot things must be implement. So more elegant way to do that

```
<Style TargetType="ToolTip">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="500" />
</Style>
```

Comment: This is actually a very good and clean solution with much reuse. I think using x:Type also is even stricter and cleaner in the TargetType.

Comment: Just because I use a lot of custom tooltips. I think you should move the max width property onto the actual textblock style. This means all of your default tooltips have a max width, but all of your custom tooltips define their own parameters.

Answer (score 31):

I realise that this is an old question, but no one seems to have suggested the most obvious and simplest solution to this problem yet. As such, I thought I'd add it here:

```
<Button>
    <Button.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip MaxWidth="400">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </ToolTip>
    </Button.ToolTip>
</Button>
```

Comment: Simplest one solution!

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<Window.Resources>
 <Style TargetType="ToolTip" x:Key="TT">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"  MaxWidth="400" TextWrapping='Wrap' />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
 </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Button>
    <Button.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Style="{StaticResource TT}">
  bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbdddddddddddddddddbbbmmmmmmhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
        </ToolTip>
    </Button.ToolTip>
</Button>
```

**Edit:**

```
<Button>
    <Button.ToolTip>
        <RichTextBox>
           <FlowDocument>
              <Paragraph>
                This is flow content and you can <Bold>edit me!</Bold>
              </Paragraph>
           </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
    </Button.ToolTip>
</Button>
```

see :[RichTextBox Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970779.aspx)

Comment: I should not change control's content. Button should appear like as my question (with stackpanel that has two textblock).

Comment: @iremce Button of my example is the same as yours. You have set its Tooltip to be a StackPanel, But I change it to be a Tooltip with your style. I think you should explain your goal. Why not to use the Tooltip style? Do you want the ToolTip to show two paragraphs?

Comment: Yes, tooltip of button or other control can consist of one more than paragraphs. I should not change the tooltip structure of controls..

Comment: @iremce You can use RichTextBox control. It is much more flexible. see my edit

Comment: I don't have permission to change structure of controls. So I can not use RichTextBox.. In addtion I editted my button example..